# Displaying dynamic table in PrimeFaces

Tags: java, sql, primefaces, mybatis

I have a data from SQL (1):

```
+------------+---------+---------+
|  Employee  |  AMNT   |  DATE   |
+------------+---------+---------+
| John       | 100     | 12-MAY  |
| Mary       | 120     | 12-MAY  |
| John       | 110     | 13-MAY  |
| Kate       |  30     | 13-MAY  |
| Mary       | 230     | 13-MAY  |
| ...        | ...     | ...     |
| ...        | ...     | 16-JUN  |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

I put in the List of the objects and this data can be shown in PrimeFaces as:

```
<p:dataTable id="resultTable" var="result" value="#{myBean.searchResult}">
    <p:column headerText="Employee">
        <h:outputText value="#{result.empName}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Amount">
        <h:outputText value="#{result.amnt}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Date">
        <h:outputText value="#{result.date}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

But it is necessary to display this data in Java application with horizontal scroll as following (2):

```
+------------+---------+---------+------+---------+
|  Employee  |  12-MAY |  13-MAY |  ... |  16-JUN |
+------------+---------+---------+------+---------+
| John       | 100     |   110   |      |         |
| Mary       | 120     |   130   |      |         |
| Kate       |         |    30   |      |         |
+------------+---------+---------+------+---------+
```

I don't use PIVOT function from Oracle SQL as my project uses MyBatis framework and fixed column names are preferable (it is possible to use aliases, but column count can be 30+).
So I decided to take data from first table (1) and transform it in Java.

Which structure it is easier to use to make such a table and how to display such a structure as PrimeFaces dataTable?

Comment: PrimeFaces cannot help here (nor should it). You have to 'transform' this yourself in either a backing bean, or using database tools.

Comment: Maybe my question is not so clear.
1) Which data structure to choose for such as transformed data (2). Is Object[][] ok? Or it is something better?
2) How to display array as datatable?

Comment: 1: check primefaces datatables colums example. 2: do the same

Comment: I know I'm late to this conversation, but PrimeFaces has a similar example here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/group.xhtml